# Performance I/O degrades after changing mysql data directory?

Tags: performance

MYSQL server is installed on windows environment : Windows server 2012 R2
PHYSICAL installed RAM : 672 GB
C : drive 1 TB and D Drive : 15 TB

We had recently database crash because of C drive full as mysql data directory was located on c drive.

Before Database crash, I/O throughput was very high and it went 1500 rows/sec
After database crash ,it went to 800 rows /sec

Nothing has changed on table, we moved Data directory of mysql to D drive and base directory to C drive, will it matters ? If it not ,then what would be cause that brought low to I/O throughput?

My.ini file config:

**1. INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE=400G

2. INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_INSTANCES=24

3. INNODB_READ_IO_THREADS=64

4. INNODB_WRITE_IO_THREADS=64

5. INNODB_LRU_SCAN_depth=2500

6. INNODB IO capacity =2000

7. INNODB_io_capacity_max=4000

8. MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=1024M**

Anyone help me on this? Its been quite 25 days I'm researching on this, feel i like data directory should be placed on C drive ,but not sure on this ?

Comment: You moved the MySQL data directory from the 1 TB drive to the 15 TB drive, and now IO is slower?  Have you looked at the specifications for the two drives?  Such as maximum and sustained transfer rates, or specified seek times?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes it is moved to 1TB to 15 TB , 15 TB drive has raid controller and good transfer rates.